# How do I group one to many in a nested fashion with linq to entities?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have three tables, `Chart`, `ChartQuestion`, `ChartAnswer`

A `Chart` has many `ChartQuestions`, a `ChartQuestion` has many `ChartAnswers`.

I'd like to do a linq query that gives me an object containing all of this data, so it'd be a `ChartObject` containing `List<ChartQuestion>` and each `ChartQuestion` contains a `List<ChartAnswer>`

I started with this:

```
(from chart in db.Chart
join chartQuestion in db.chartQuestion on chart.ChartId equals chartQuestion.ChartId into chartQuestions)
```

This seems to be the first step. However I want to include the ChartAnswers now, so I have to do another join to pull back the ChartAnswers but I don't know how to do this.

I can't do a join, and while I can do a from, I am not sure of the exact syntax.

```
(from chart in db.Chart
join chartQuestion in db.chartQuestion on chart.ChartId equals chartQuestion.ChartId into chartQuestions
from chartQuestionsSelection in chartQuestions
join chartAnswer in context.ChartAnswers on chartQuestions.ChartAnswerId equals chartAnswer.ChartAnswerId into chartAnswers // This is wrong
)
```

With that code above you end up as chartAnswers being separate to the chartQuestions rather than belonging to them, so I don't think it is correct.

Any idea?

Comment: Use navigation properties, that's what they're for.

Answer (score 1):

joining a table destructors it i.e. you now have the row as a variable if you need it in a nested fashion then select in like this

```
(from chart in db.Chart
select new { //can also be your own class/record, perhaps a DTO
   chart.Id,
   chart.Name,
   questions = (from chartQuestion in db.chartQuestion
               where chart.ChartId == chartQuestion.ChartId
               select new { //perhaps a dto
                    chartQuestion.Id,
                    chartQuestion.Question,
                    Answers = 
                       (from chartAnswer in context.ChartAnswers
                       where chartAnswer.ChartAnswerId == chartQuestion.ChartAnswerId
                       select chartAnswer).ToList() //this is translated and not evaluated
           }).ToList() //this is translated not evaluated
}).ToListAsync(cancellationToken) //this will evaluate the expression
```

If you *need* it by joins then you can group join it like this:

```
from m in _context.Chart
join d in _context.ChartQuestions
    on m.ID equals d.ID into mdJoin
select new
{
    chartId = m.ID,
    chartName = "m.name",
    quess = from d in mdJoin
            join dd in _context.ChartAnswer
                on d.Iddomain equals dd.DomainId into anJoin
            select new
            {
                quesId = d.ID,
                quesName = d.Question,
                anss = anJoin
            }
}
```

**A better way:** If you edit your DbConfigurations to include navigation properties of each then the code will become way simpler.

example:

```
db.Chart
   .Include(x => x.chartQuestions)
       .ThenInclude(x => x.chartAnswers)
```

You can search more about how to do navigation properties in EFCore, but ofcourse if the code base is large then this might not be feasible for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
(from chart in db.Chart
join chartQuestion in db.chartQuestion on chart.ChartId equals chartQuestion.ChartId
join chartAnswer in context.ChartAnswers on  chartAnswer.ChartAnswerId equals chartQuestion.ChartAnswerId
)
```

Comment: If I do this, then my chartQuestion items are only linked to a single chartAnswer, presumably because it creates one row for each. So I could do that and then filter and join them, but I thought it might be possible to do this grouping as part of the query itself

Comment: The you need to a Group by : (from ....... select new {chart = chart, chartQuestion = chartQuestion, chartAnswer = chartAnswer).GroupBy(x => chart.ChartId)

Comment: Yes, but applying the grouping is the part I am having trouble with. I think that `into` is the answer but doing a nested `into` is the problem

Comment: Why do you need the into?  Into is only need if you are doing a left outer join and you do not have the default() in your query so I assume you do not need the left outer join.